# How Do I Prevent Youtube From Adjusting My Mic Volume?

Tags: audio, youtube, microphone

Every time I try to record a livestream, my mic levels go all the way up, ruining whatever content I'm trying to make. It seems to only happen when I'm livestreaming on Youtube. I've gone into my mic settings and unchecked the boxes that allow programs to access it.  I've uninstalled Skype and Discord, and I made sure Steam's settings don't interfere with the mic. Is it possible that Youtube is doing this, and is there a setting I don't know about? So far, I can't find one.

Comment: My question contains the exact amount of specificity necessary to address the very specific issue I'm having, which is that it appears that Youtube is adjusting my mic level while I livestream. Most people would say to check my mic settings and settings in programs like Skype and Discord, so I mentioned that I already did that in order to save time. Since posting this I have troubleshooted the issue and discovered that my browser, Chrome, is what's responsible. What I still don't know is how to fix this so I can use Chrome while livestreaming on Youtube. 
But hopefully this could help.